How to identify Hypothesis for Contra Positive
Helping my son with his Logical Thinking study but struggling with identifying hypothesis.
For "If P then Q", books, tutorial videos and articles suggest that P is the hypothesis (Its Contra Positive is: If NOT Q then NOT P).
However, for "to" instead of "if-then" statement I find it difficult, eg.
"To pass exam, you studied hard": The hypothesis seems to be "you studied hard" so if I reword them:
"If you studied hard then you passed exam", but it can also be "If you passed exam then you studied hard". My doubt is because for each one I can say "study hard does not guarantee passing" and "you can pass exam with lucky-guess".
"To be a doctor, you passed entrance exam": The hypothesis seems to be "be a doctor" so if I reword them:
"If you are a doctor then you passed entrance exam", but it can also be "If you passed entrance exam then you are a doctor".
Since there can be only 1 correct contrapositive, which ones of the above are correct?
Is hypothesis based on subjective judgement or text structure?
Is there any rule/method to verify I chose the correct text for hypothesis?

"To pass exam" is missing an article, and "To pass the exam, you studied hard" isn't a conditional.

You have an “infinitive of purpose” here — not a conditional. [In order] to pass exam, you studied hard.

There is a philosophy stack exchange https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ which would be a better place to ask about the nature of logical propositions, inferences, contrapositives, etc. They seem to accept a wide range of questions at different levels.

In "If P then Q", you have a pure logical function. In "To pass exam, you studied hard" you are entering the realm of language and complex relations not taken into account by  mathematical logic, which is a comparatively simple representation of reality. In this latter utterance there is the added notion of causality: "it is because you studied hard that you passed your exams.". In "You studied hard and you passed your exams." the causality is not explicit, but it is often conceived to be a property of the conjunction "and" (Reversing the order of the conjuncts would not do, which shows that there is no pure conjunction in this sentence); therefore you can't apply the principles of logic to that; there is no way to speak of "conjuncts" in the mathematical sense of modern logic. Similarly, you can't speak of hypothesis and conclusion in relation to such sentences as "To pass exam, you studied hard".
That is not to say that all uterances are modelled on principles that involve always more than pure logic. Here is an instance  which shows a case of  pure logic.

Provided that you study, you have a chance to pass your exams.

As long as  you study, you have a chance to pass your exams. (synonymous)


"Provided that" is equivalent to mathelmatical "if"; "then" is not explicitly coded, but is implied; "you study" is the hypothesis, the last part is the conclusion.

Precise and compact. Good answer.
